# CSS Transforms in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-transforms

Hi am using css transform in scale property my code is like this

```
-webkit-transform: scale(1.05); /* Safari and Chrome */ 
-moz-transform: scale(1.05);    /* Firefox */
-o-transform: scale(1.05);      /* Opera */
-ms-transform: scale(1.05);     /* IE 9 */
transform: scale(1.05);
```

Here not supported in ie7 letyou known the answer please reply me ASAP.

Comment: You haven’t actually asked a question there.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I understand your question. CSS transforms are not supported in IE8 or older, where you have to have to use an IE matrix filter in order to achieve the same effect (scale or rotate).

Like this (code for IE8 and older, check it live **with IE8 or older** at http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/5XdSy/ ):

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(
            M11=1.05,
            M12=0,
            M21=0,
            M22=1.05,
            SizingMethod='auto expand');
```

Also, your code is CSS and you've put it between div tags.

Answer (score 3):

Older IE browsers don't support CSS transformations. Try using a polyfill like [Transformie](http://paulbakaus.com/2008/08/16/bringing-css-transform-to-internet-explorer/).

Comment: Your link leads to broken links. You can find [the plugin](https://github.com/pbakaus/transformie) on GitHub.