# Using 'alt' and 'title' tags for 'area' with css 'zoom' property in IE

Tags: html, css

In the following script, the `area` tag defined as a clickable area inside the center of the image-map. 
The `alt` tag specifies text for the area, and the `zoom` property controls the magnification level to 50% zoom out of the original image:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #myimg {zoom:50%; -moz-transform:scale(50%); -webkit-transform:scale(50%);}
</style>

<img src="http://www.content.onemexico.net/rosa.jpg" id="myimg" width="640" height="640" usemap="#themap">
<map name="themap">
    <area shape="rect" coords="240,240,400,400" alt="RosesByAlt" title="RosesByTitle" href="#">
</map>
```

The description text for the clickable area is showing up in all major browsers except Internet Explorer (IE-9).

I tried the `title` attributes instead the `alt`, but still the text doesn't appear.

Please anybody can help make the description text to appear for clickable area with the zoom property using Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

IE9 works with the standard CSS `transform` property. It needs a prefix, but it does support it. So if you're just trying to support IE9, you don't need the `zoom` at all. You should be able to do this:

```
#myimg {
    -ms-transform:scale(0.5);
    -o-transform:scale(0.5);
    -moz-transform:scale(0.5);
    -webkit-transform:scale(0.5);
    transform:scale(0.5);
}
```

If you need to support IE8 or earlier, then you'll need the `zoom` or something similar, but beware that `zoom` is not the same as `scale`; it may have some similarities on the surface, but it works quite differently, and you will get some weird effects if you use it.

So I would recommend not using `zoom` at all, even for old IE versions. You'll be better off using either IE's `matrix` filter or a polyfill script to backport support for the `transform` style into old IEs. The [answers provided here may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651734/css-transforms-in-ie7)

Also note that I've added the un-prefixed version of the property as well: you should always provide the un-prefixed version of all properties, even if no browser supports it yet, because at some time in the future they will all drop support for their prefixed version, at which point your code will break if you haven't got the standard version in there.

Comment: Thank you, I have changed the css to yours, but the image magnification doesn't work, ie – the picture stays in its original size.

Comment: IE9 and Chrome (picture stays in its original size)

Comment: hmm, you might want to create a jsFiddle to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Edit: after changing your code from 50% to 0.5, it works for Chrome, but not for IE9 (picture stays in its original size)

Comment: ah yes, it's a fractional value. I actually got the 50% from your original question, but I should have remembered to change it. Sorry.

Comment: But the problem still exist

Comment: as I said, a jsfiddle would help. I'm afraid I'm out of time; I can't help much more. You could try `scale(0.5,0.5)`. But create a jsfiddle and add a link to it to the question, and it may help get further answers.