# jquery resize div when min/max width matches certain width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how do I re-size a div gradually to 0 if as window width is under x px or %, and back to max-width when window bigger than x px or % ?

Comment: Please post your code, what have you tried so far? What does your DOM structure look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would normally be done with CSS, using a CSS transition property, and then using jQuery's addClass

CSS

```
#myElementToResize{
    width: 100px;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s;
    transition: width 2s;
}
.minimized{
    width: 0px;
}
```

JS

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ( $(window).width() <= 768 ){
        $("#myElementToResize").addClass("minimized");
    } else {
        $("#myElementToResize").removeClass("minimized");
    }
})
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention in the question that I also needed to support IE7, does it work without transition as it appear in IE9+ ?

Comment: This will not work in IE7, though im not sure why you are trying to run animations in a decade old browser in the first place. Here is a resource that may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651734/css-transforms-in-ie7

Answer (score 0):

Run this example on full page.

Adding a `resizeTimer` to provide a little bit of time lapse before firing the resize event.

```js
var resizeTimer;

$(window).on('resize',function(){
    clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
    resizeTimer = setTimeout(function(){
        $("#theDiv").height($(window).height()/5);//calculation for height here as required
    }, 200);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="theDiv" style="background-color: yellow; border: 1px solid black; height: 100px"></div>
```