# Re size iframe based on width of window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have an iframe embedded in a third party website, which I cannot edit in any way.

I want the iframe to re-size according to the width of the window.

If I was able to edit the whole page, this would not be a problem.

However, when setting the size of an element in %, it uses the parent of that element to size from. In the case of the page I am working with, the parent elements do not re-size, so this does not work.

What I need, is a way of telling the iframe to re size, based solely on the width of the window, and preferably using only CSS.

Is this possible using only CSS? If not is it possible using JQuery or JavaScript?

Comment: does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324712/jquery-resize-div-when-min-max-width-matches-certain-width/31325107#31325107  ??

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/6aLxaag8/2/

This jsfiddle loads a second jsfiddle in the iframe.

There's a hardcoded `style` attribute on the IFrame that sets the width; `100vw` or [100% of the width of the viewing window](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units) in which the element sits, regardless of it's position in the DOM. As you don't have access to the parent page you'll need to use a style attribute and you may not be able to use javascript to add it (check cross site scripting).

[Support isn't perfect](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) with `vw` units, but it's close.

PS, it's hard to know if this will work without trying it in your context, please let me know :-)

Comment: I have been told to leave this for now so will not be able to test this for the moment. Will bear this in mind though-it seems like it could possibly. Upvote for good answer

Comment: @Alex fair enough, I'd still be curious to know if it would help, flag me if you do try!

Comment: will do, I will let you know

Answer (score -1):

I have encountered that problem before and I use this css trick, this adjust to the width & height of any wrapper/div so if you have embed an iframe inside a div with 'height: 620px' and 'width: 420px'  the iframe size adjust to the div's height and width. Just change both width & height of the div to 100% percent.

```css
.content_here {
    width: 420px;
    height: 620px; 
}

iframe#iframecontent {
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content_here">
  <iframe id="iframecontent" src="http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"  scrolling="auto"></iframe>
 </div>
```

Comment: OP has no control over the site in which the IFrame is embedded