# How to do translate3d type effect for older versions of IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, leaflet, css-transforms

On a site I'm working on, I have css that uses translate3d to style it accordingly.
Example:

```
style="transform: translate3d(-133px, -8px, 0px);"
```

However, I now need to address this in older versions of IE.  What other ways can it be done?  Is there a way to use filters or something else to make it happen?

Comment: older IE versions have filters and affects that can do very similar things...target the version via conditional comments and apply the proprietary styles.apis to the desired element(s)

Comment: Maybe useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651734/css-transforms-in-ie7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe negative margins would help: `margin-left: -133px; margin-top: -8px;` but it might depend on parent element styles.

Comment: Thanks @pavelccz!!!  Looks like this will work perfectly for what I need.  Not sure how I would handle it if the translate3d had 3 values supplied, but fortunately I don't have that situation currently as the 3rd in my case are all 0's.

Answer (score 0):

Altering the margins as noted above by @pavelccz will work and is probably best suited for most situations. Encountering this with leaflet as in my case, leaflet provides a global switch that will result in the same affect throughout the map.  Using the switch of "L_DISABLE_3D = false" is the most practical for that situation.  As noted in the documentation, this could impact performance, but it is a global way to address this issue.

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#global-l_disable_3d